# Getting wav files corresponding to each frame in the video with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to extract images and sounds from the video separately (in sync). I am extracting the images as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i inputvideo.mp4 -r 24.0 videoimage%4d.jpg
```

How can I extract corresponding sound data into separate wav files? For example, frame rate of one of the video files is 24 and audio sampling rate is 48,000. Audio of the first frame would be first 2000 samples (if I am not mistaken about what is sampling rate).

Comment: It might be the easiest way to just dump the audio in PCM format, then use dd to cut the needed pieces.

Comment: @EugenRieck Is there a specific reason you mention PCM format? I was thinking about extract whole audio as a vaw file than separate chunks programmatically via some other way.

Comment: PCM is the classic raw format - it has the nice property that you can very easily calculate offset and length in a script. It also allows seamless joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up first extracting all sound as a single audio file (either wav or pcm). Then wrote a script that reads samples in the audio file, divides them into chunks and save them separately as binary files.
If there is a command line only solution with ffmpeg, let me know and I will update the answer. Thanks.